# Basic black-box text assertion in Enzyme shallow render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

Say I have the following component:

```js
const MyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <Foo>
      <Bar>
        <Lee>
          Hello!
        </Lee>
      </Bar>
    </Foo>
  </div>
)
```

I want to render it shallowly, and I want to black-box test it so I don't have any knowledge of the subcomponents (`Foo`, `Bar`, `Lee`), and ultimately I just want to make sure it contains the text "Hello!".

```js
shallow(<MyComponent />).text()
```

just returns `<Foo />`.

```js
shallow(<MyComponent />).html()
```

seems like it's actually digging into the implementation of each one of those subcomponents, maybe defeating the purpose of it being shallow (and certainly not being a black-box test)?

```js
shallow(<MyComponent />).debug()
```

honestly kind of gives me what I'd expect and be able to make assertions against, but that clearly isn't the intent (and I'd imagine isn't optimized for performance).

In the docs it shows something like

```js
shallow(<MyComponent />).find("Lee").text()
```

but that couples my test with the implementation of `MyComponent` which certainly seems undesirable (making it a white-box test at least).

What's the best way to use shallow to make an assertion that a component has the content you want it to for a black-box test?

Comment: If you are using `shallow()` why just not test a `<Lee>` since it makes more sense and more clear in terms of unit testing?

Comment: `Lee` is a vendor component, and is really an implementation detail that it happens to be wrapping the "Hello" at this time.  That's very likely to change.  In terms of unit testing, I don't care that it's wrapped in a `Lee`, I care that it's present.

Comment: Updated the description to specify that I want it to be a black-box test.